# How to suppress findings on old/superseded AWS ECR images on AWS Inspector?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, amazon-inspector

We are using AWS Inspector to scan vulnerabilities on our AWS ECR repositories. When there is a new image on a certain repository, we would like to suppress findings from past / superseded images, keep active only findings from the latest image for each repository, so we can see only the issues that are actually not fixed yet.

I can't just filter out by age, because it might happen that we don't generate a new image for some time, for certain repositories.

I'm trying to create suppression rules on AWS Inspector, but I can't find the proper filter to achieve the desired effect. If I try to suppress all images that don't have the `latest` Image Tag, it suppresses all images, with `latest` tag included.

How can I suppress findings from old ECR images?

Comment: A suppression rule that filters image tags not equal `latest` should work. If you look at the "Findings suppressed by this rule" table, do you see the "Impacted resource" with the SHA of the image tagged with latest?

Comment: I thought the same. But it doesn't. Say that I have an issue A on a previous image and the same issue on the latest image (same repo). And I have the rule to suppress everything but latest. It will supress issue A, including on the latest version, I guess because a previous image have the issue.

Comment: I'm have the same issue, in my case, further complicated by the fact that I have multiple tags on an image, which seems to confuse the situation further, in that if I suppress findings based on the basis of not:latest, but there is another tag on that image, then the findings are suppressed, since the suppression algo sees that there is A tag on the image that isn't called "latest"  GREEDY suppression rules!  anyways, no real solutions here, just frustration.

Comment: It looks like that suppression rules aren't suppressing findings (a vulnerability found in an image from a repository) but rather a whole vulnerability (a vulnerability found across all images in a repository)  IMO, Inspector should support both.